# Generate new format from a non-system generated report using Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have an excel file which is non-system generated report format. 
I wish to calculate and generate another new output.

Given the Report format as below:-

1) Inside the query when load this excel file, how can I create a new column to copy and paste on the first found value (1#51) at column at the next record, if the next record is empty. Once, if detected a new value (1#261) then copy and paste to the subsequent null value of few next records till this end?

[image]

2) The final aim is to generate a new output to auto match/calculate the money to be assign to different reference. As shown below:-

The reference A ~ E is sharing the 3 bank Ref (28269,28542 & RMP) , was thinking to read the same data source a few times, first time to read the column A ~ O(QueryRef)   and 2nd time to read the same source to read from A, Q ~ V(QueryBank).

After this I do not have idea how I can allocate the $$ from Query Bank to QueryRef based on the Sum of Total AR.

Eg,

- Total Amt of BankRef 28269, $57,044.67 is sufficient to cover Ref#A $10,947.12
- BankRef 28269 still sufficient to cover Ref#B $27,647.60
- BankRef 28269 left only $18,449.95 , hence the balance of 28269 be allocate to Ref#C.
- Remaining balance of Ref#C will need to use BankRef28542 to cover,i.e. $1,812.29
- Ref#D will then be allocated of the remaining balance of BankRef28542, i.e. $4,595.32
- Ref#D still left $13,350.03 unallocated, hence this will use BankRef#RMP
- Ref#E only need $597.66, and BankRef#RMP is sufficient to cover this.

[image]

I am not sure if my above case study can be solved using power query or not, due to me still being a newbie @ Power Query? Or this is too complicate to handle hence we need to write a program to auto matching this kinds of scenario?

Attached is the sample source file and output :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dyecwcdz2qg549y/AACzezsXBwAf8eHUNxxLD1eWa?dl=0

Any advice/opinion/guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure anyone can give me some clues, if the 2nd part of the question is do-able in power query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering question one: 
You have a feature in Powerquery called FILL, [DOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-filldown) or [UP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fillup).

For a selected column you can copy the first non empty value to all rows under until a new non empty row is found and so on.